# Java .startsWith optimization

Tags: java, optimization, startswith

So I got a question. Today I started optimizing my code and got to this point for example:

```
return !this.message.startsWith("/");
```

Well follow where I took my optimization tips from [here](http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/optimization.html#rule75) (linked to the rule)

And so how should be that code written to more optimized version?
I currently got:

```
return !(this.message.length () > ZERO) && this.message.charAt(ZERO) == Slash;
```

Did I write it right?
And if I wrote it wrong, then what did I write wrong?

Thanks,
tambre

Comment: Do you need to optimize it? The first one is a lot more readable...

Comment: why have you created named constant for '0'? that looks terrible.

Comment: I doubt that it will be much faster...

Comment: @Yossarian:  That can simplify modifying the program, should the value of zero change  :-)  http://geekslop.com/2012/funny-computer-programmer-quotes

Comment: Going through the rules on that website: some make sense but some are really useless.

Comment: A shocking list. Worst I've ever seen, and I've seen some doozies. Items {6,14-7,19,38,48,55,72,76,78-9,80-1,112-3,125,129,131} are definitely incorrect, and many of them have nothing to do with performance at all. Items {9,12,21,23,29,33-4,41,50-2,54,58,75,82,83,97,100,109,115} are dubious at best. 4 is just a stupid thing that nobody actually does. {10-11} cite code that wouldn't work in the first place. 59 is unintelligible. {62-67} are identical, as are {90-93,114} and {32,122-3}. I agree with {19 'avoid unnecessary parentheses'} but it has absolutely nothing to do with performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put aside the validity of the rule you cite (which I disagree with, by the way, because I think making the code less readable is a worse sin than any minor performance improvement—if any—that transformation might provide), the resulting code should be:

```
return !(this.message.length () > ZERO && this.message.charAt(ZERO) == Slash);
```

You have the parentheses around only the first term of the condition, which is wrong. A slightly more readable version would be:

```
return this.message.length () <= ZERO || this.message.charAt(ZERO) != Slash;
```

Comment: Nice example of an optimisation that does not optimise anything and turns a correct code into a buggy one :-)

Comment: Remember early optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: @anakata - Or, as the saying goes, "I'd rather optimize a debugged program than debug an optimized one."